# Laravel 4 AUTH via AJAX, possible session issue

Tags: php, ajax, authentication, laravel, laravel-4

I've done it in previous projects using Sentry 2, but I can't get it to work with the built-in Auth functionality.

User store method:

```
public function store()
{
    $validation = new Services\Validators\User;

    if ($validation->passesForStore()) {
        // Create a new user
        $user = new User;
        $user->name     = Input::get('name');
        $user->password = Input::get('password');
        $user->email    = Input::get('email');
        $user->save();

        // Authenticate the user
        Auth::loginUsingId($user->id);

        return JSend::success([
            'redirect' => URL::action('VaultController@index')
        ]);
    }

    // Provide a custom message for an e-mailaddress that's already in use
    $message = '';
    if ($validation->hasFailed('email', 'unique')) {
        $message = 'This e-mailaddress has already been taken';
    }

    return JSend::fail([
        'failed' => $validation->failedFields(),
        'message' => $message
    ]);
}
```

The AJAX response handler:

```
// Redirect to given URL
if (typeof response.data.redirect != 'undefined') {
    window.location = response.data.redirect;
}
```

The user is successfully created, placing an `Auth::check();` directly after the `loginUsingId` results in `true` but as soon as the page is redirected by `window.location`, `Auth::check()` results in false and the user is not logged in, not even when manually navigating to a different page.

App.session settings:

```
'lifetime' => 120,
'expire_on_close' => true,
```

Bare in mind that the login method works in a similar way but doesn't work either!
(it does work without the use of AJAX)

**=== UPDATE ===**

Life just got a little weirder. <strike>I can now login using my login and register methods.
What changed? I added a vhost alias for my former localhost project and logging in seemed
to work fine. (Sounds to me like an environment issue?).</strike>

What doesn't work however is logging out. I created the following route for test purposes:

```
Route::get('logout', function(){
    Auth::logout();
    Session::flush();

    dd(Auth::check());
});
```

The result is, as expected, `false`. However! If I then go to my login page I get redirected. Visiting my other debug route below results in `true` which makes absolutely
no sense at all. The user was not logged in using the 'remember' flag.

```
Route::get('authenticated', function(){
    dd(Auth::check());
});
```

Any input is highly appreciated at this point :)

**=== UPDATE 2 ===**

It seems the previous successful attempt was just a fluke. Logging in, or logging out after I manually logged myself in doesn't work.. Any way to debug this kind of black magic?

**=== UPDATE 3 ===**

Today I tried my app once more and was presented with an can't write to session file xxxx error. I checked my storage/sessions folder and found that no such file existed.

I emptied the storage/sessions folder, cleared all cache, and weird enough the login and
logout problems I had before are gone.

Even though the primary issue is solved (for now) I would still like to find out what caused this problem in the first place

Comment: Try with `location.assign(response.data.redirect);`  (maybe  the current page should be saved in session history ) I'm not sure

Comment: As expected this doesn't change anything. location.assign(), afaik, should have the same result as location.href.

Comment: Howcome you are using a custom validator to validate the credentials?

Comment: I don't see how this is relevant for my OP, but to shed some light: I use Laravel's validator class but wrote a very small wrapper that allows me to use a basic ruleset for all model properties, and add specific rules based on different scenarios (eg: create, store or login).

Comment: maybe this post will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23536877/laravel-4-persisting-data-ongoing-jquery-ajax-submit, let us know if it works