# Laravel 4 sessions fail after redirect

Tags: session, laravel, authentication, laravel-4

Briefly, I send ajax request to this function and reloads the page via js if auth::attempt returns true.

Problem is that, from ajax response
- Auth::admin()->check() returns true,
- Auth::admin()->get()->id returns correct id
but after reloading page, Auth::admin()->check() returns false and the other one throws exception.

The interesting thing is this code working perfectly on local but gives this strange status on remote server(host).

There are dozen of advices about this problem, I listed below what I tried to solve this issue so please look at these before giving advice.

- app/storage/session permissions 0777
- php 5.5
- tried when session driver is file, database, cookie, array. There is no problem when setting cookie and adding row on sessions table when driver is database.
- There is no problem with primary key, besides this code works perfectly on local.
- I use https://github.com/ollieread/multiauth for multi auth, removed this plugin and tried default auth component but the result was the same.

I hope some laravel master guys find a way to solve this.

```
public function login() {

    $username        = Input::get('username');
    $pass            = Input::get('pass');
    $remember        = Input::has('remember');

    $credentials     = array('admin_name' => $username, 'password' => $pass);
    $status          = FALSE;
    if ( Auth::admin()->attempt($credentials, $remember) ) 
        $status = TRUE;

    echo json_encode(array(
        "status"      => $status,
        "action"      => "login",
        "message"     => $status ? trans("admin/codes.002") : trans("admin/codes.001"),
        "ex" => Auth::admin()->get()->id,
        "xe" => Auth::admin()->check()
    ));

    return;
}
```

Comment: did you try to login the user manually after auth attempt?

Comment: @mdamia I tried but nothing has changed. What was the purpose ?

Comment: Here is the solution,
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23536877/laravel-4-persisting-data-ongoing-jquery-ajax-submit